# r split columns at intervals and store product in variables

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix that has 2 rows and 5000 variables in each. I need to split the columns at intervals of 50 such that I get 100 separate matrix entities each of 2 rows and 50 variables. Then I need to be able to create a function that can iterate through each of the 100 entities... I'm hoping for suggestions on the code but also I need to know if I should store the split entities in a variable (or somehow even separate variables) in order to iterate through each of them? Or will splitting them and then performing the function on the original matrix suffice to get output results for each of the matrices within?

Comment: or even better should I perform the function first and have it such that it iterates through at intervals of 50 and then split those results?

Comment: Actually I just managed to transpose the whole thing so it's now two columns of 5000 variables that I need to split at intervals of 50

Answer (score 0):

We create a grouping variable ('i2') and `split` the sequence of columns by that variable.  The output will be a `list` ('lst').  We subset the 'm1' based on the column index in each `list` element.  We can change the `names` of the 'lst' and then create multiple objects in the global environment (not recommended as most of the operations can be done within the `list` itself) using `list2env`.

```
i1 <- seq_len(ncol(m1))
i2 <- (i1-1)%/%50 +1
lst <- lapply(split(i1, i2), function(i) m1[,i])
names(lst) <- paste0('newm', seq_along(lst))
list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)  
newm1
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(24)
 m1 <- matrix(sample(0:9, 5000*2, replace=TRUE), nrow=2)
```

Comment: Thank you this looks really detailed. I tried it but got an error message fo the first line.
Error in seq_len(ncol(x)) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
In addition: Warning message:
In seq_len(ncol(x)) : first element used of 'length.out' argument

Comment: @Chris Based on the data provided in my post, I am not getting any warning messages or error.